# Tailwind: Centered div on top of image

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div>
<img src="">
<div><!-- centered form on top of the image --></div>
</div>
```

[Here is how the layout should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB0S7.jpg)

How do I do it with Tailwind? The solution has to be responsive. I don't want to use a background-image CSS property. I would like to use an `<img>` tag instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does the markup have to be that way? How about something like this:

```
<div class="container mx-auto bg-gray-500 w-1/2 p-4 relative">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="" class="w-full h-auto">
  <div class="bg-red-300 w-1/2 h-1/2 absolute top-1/4 left-1/4 rounded-lg p-4">div</div>
</div>
```

See it live: https://play.tailwindcss.com/IxHzcdTq1a

Comment: This seems working but in my case, the 'div' content is higher than the height of the image, the form is spread into the bottom of the page